# Make footnotemark work in beamer overlayarea - a footnote predicament

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I am trying to add a footnote to something in an `overlayarea`. The `overlayarea` is required to make the *picture stay in exactly the same spot* in consecutive slides, regardless of the length of the `itemize`.

[image]

The standard `\footnote` command places the footnotes inside the `overlayarea`. I don't want that! Using `\footnote[frame]` however again destroys the picture alignment.

To get it at least approximately to the bottom without messing with the picture, I tried `\footnotemark` and after appropriate `\vspace*` the`\footnotetext`. This would be acceptable, if the label was picked up.

How can I get the footnote label?

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image-a} \\
        \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{0.5\textheight}
            \only<1>{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item A
                    \item B
                    \item C
                \end{itemize}
            }
            \only<2>{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item D\footnotemark
                    \item E%\footnote{Footnote concerning E.}
                    \item F
                    \item G
                \end{itemize}
                \vspace*{2.5cm} % Push footnote approximately to bottom.
                \footnotetext{Footnote concering D.}
            }
        \end{overlayarea}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of fighting with the footnotes, I suggest to use a top aligned frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image-a} \\
%        \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{0.5\textheight}
            \only<1>{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item A
                    \item B
                    \item C
                \end{itemize}
            }
            \only<2>{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item D\footnote{Footnote concering D.}
                    \item E%\footnote{Footnote concerning E.}
                    \item F
                    \item G
                \end{itemize}
            }
%        \end{overlayarea}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But to answer your original question: Use the footnotetext outside of the overlay area. This makes the manual spacing superfluous and show a number.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \includegraphics[height=0.3\textheight]{example-image-a} \\
        \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{0.5\textheight}
            \only<1>{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item A
                    \item B
                    \item C
                \end{itemize}
            }
            \only<2>{
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item D\footnotemark
                    \item E%\footnote{Footnote concerning E.}
                    \item F
                    \item G
                \end{itemize}   
            }
        \end{overlayarea}
        \only<2>{\footnotetext{Footnote concering D.}}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, in your second solution, the picture gets shifted vertically by the footnote, so this is not an option.

Comment: @Christoph90 You could use `\footnotetext<2>{Footnote concering D.}` but then the rule is also present on the first overlay