# Footnote citation in beamer with disappearing image

Tags: beamer, biblatex, itemize, footcite, only

I am preparing the presentation for my master's thesis dissertation using beamer.

In a frame, I have a list of items, with an image I want to hide in the second slide using `\only<1>`. However, the first item contains a citation I am inserting with `\footcite`. At first, I was surrounding everything with an `overlayarea`, but the resulting footnote was not aligned with the others and the footnote mark was not consistent.

Following [this SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427708/make-footnotemark-work-in-beamer-overlayarea-a-footnote-predicament), I moved it to a top aligned frame and the result looks better. Anyway, the footnote is not shown in the first slide (when the image is visualized) even though the mark is present, and I do not get why.

[image: My slides]

Does anybody know how may I fix it, showing the footnote in the first slide as well? Thanks in advance!

---

Here is the code I am using:

```
\begin{frame}[t]{Method}
    \framesubtitle{Adapting the Feature Pyramid Network}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> \alert{FPN}\footfullcite{lin2017feature} is widely used for object detection:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Extract feature maps at multiple levels from a single image
            \item Sequence of convolutional layers, size divided by two at consecutive stages, with top-down connections
            \item Increases detection performances, but adversarial domain alignment is non-trivial
        \end{itemize}
        \only<1>{
            \begin{center}
                \item[]
                \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{imgs/fpn.png}}
            \end{center}
        }
        \item<2-> Tested approaches:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Align levels of extracted feature pyramid
            \item Align layers of the \alert{ResNet} feature extractor, input for FPN
        \end{itemize}
        \item<2-> Extracted representation is meaningful and independent of input domain
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

I am using `pdflatex` and `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
...
\addbibresource{my_biblio.bib}
```

and the citation is contained in `my_biblio.bib`:

```
@misc{lin2017feature,
      title={Feature Pyramid Networks for Object Detection}, 
      author={Tsung-Yi Lin and Piotr Dollár and Ross Girshick and Kaiming He and Bharath Hariharan and Serge Belongie},
      year={2017}
}
```

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It's been a couple of days – did you find a solution? If not, could you please edit your code block to make it a short, compilable MWE? It should start with `\documentclass`, end with `\end{document}` and contain just enough packages and code to replicate your issue. This makes it easier to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lack of a MWE and of the local image `fpn.png` that you are importing, I could not reproduce your output exactly, but the following homemade MWE appears to replicate your issue:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{lin2017feature,
      title={Feature Pyramid Networks for Object Detection}, 
      author={Tsung-Yi Lin and Piotr Dollár and Ross Girshick and Kaiming He and Bharath Hariharan and Serge Belongie},
      year={2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Method}
    \framesubtitle{Adapting the Feature Pyramid Network}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> \alert{FPN}\footfullcite{lin2017feature} is widely used for object detection:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Extract feature maps at multiple levels from a single image
            \item Sequence of convolutional layers, size divided by two at consecutive stages, with top-down connections
            \item Increases detection performances, but adversarial domain alignment is non-trivial
        \end{itemize}
        \only<1>{
            \begin{center}
                \item[]
                \fbox{\rule{.5\textwidth}{.3\textwidth}}% a box in the approx size of your image
            \end{center}
        }
        \item<2-> Tested approaches:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Align levels of extracted feature pyramid
            \item Align layers of the \alert{ResNet} feature extractor, input for FPN
        \end{itemize}
        \item<2-> Extracted representation is meaningful and independent of input domain
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: two beamer frames, the first one is missing the page footer]

The issue appears to be that the `center` environment that contains the image takes up too much vertical space. Thus, the footnote overflows beyond the bottom page margin. It's there, but it's invisible. For comparison, a "shorter" image allows the footnote to be printed:

```
\fbox{\rule{.5\textwidth}{.1\textwidth}}
```

[image: a shorter image means enough space for the footer]

In the pics you posted, he problem comes *not from the actual picture*, but from the inordinate amount of *whitespace* below it. Some of it can be sacrificed without penalty to readability or aesthetic.

Hence, I'd recommend the following quick and dirty fix: Subtract some vertical space at the end of the `center` environment, to leave enough space for the page footer. The footnote pops up where it is expected.

```
\only<1>{
            \begin{center}
                \item[]
                \fbox{\rule{.5\textwidth}{.3\textwidth}}
            \end{center}
            \vspace{-2.5\baselineskip}
        }
```

Choose a value of this negative `vspace` that allows for the footnote without messing with the rest of the layout, remembering that `\baselineskip` = the distance between the baselines of two consecutive lines of text.

[image: the frame with some negative \vspace after \end{center}]

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you! I will try to provide a better MWE next time :)

Comment: @brio97 Very glad that it helped! :) Do consider marking the answer as "accepted" in that case (the green checkmark next to it).